# .ipynb file not displaying properly in GitHub

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, repository, jupyter

I've uploaded a **.ipynb** jupyter notebook in GitHub but it doesn't display the exact same output as I've written in jupyter notebook.

Here's the link to my repo: [ipynb file](https://github.com/akashsb18/Analysing-Dataset-Using-Pandas)

Comment: Did our answers fix your problem Akash? If they did, please consider marking it as "accepted" (clicking on the tick) and upvoting the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to view the notebook as "rendered blob" not as "source blob". In GitHub, this is done by selecting the second rendering option in the top right:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly issue with `Github` backend. Try this way instead uploading directly

Go to --> https://nbviewer.org/

Paste your `.ipynb` github link here.

[image]

You can downlaod or embedded your file directly from here..

[image]

Comment: nbviewer will create a link you can share. In OP's case, it is at https://nbviewer.org/github/akashsb18/Analysing-Dataset-Using-Pandas/blob/main/Project_01_ProjectBrief_blank.ipynb . You can deduce the pattern of these URLs by examining the URL of the nbviewer view and the Github page. So in some cases you don't even need to paste in the form once you understand the pattern. This is the Jupyter community provided utility for viewing and sharing notebooks. **It handles a lot of features that the GitHub preview doesn't**.