# nbviewer can not display vpython result

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, vpython

If a Jupyter Notebook file is rendering too long in GitHub, it is recommended [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-notebook-not-rendering-on-github-heres-a-simple-solution-e51aa6ca29b6) to show it in [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/), since it is [an issue with GitHub backend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74319406/9475509).

From [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer/blob/main/nbviewer/templates/faq.md#can-nbviewer-run-my-python-julia-r-scala-etc-notebooks), which I do not understand

> nbviewer does not execute notebooks. It only renders the inputs and outputs saved in a notebook document as a web page.

I make a notebook importing [vpython](https://vpython.org/), which is rendered locally, but can not be rendered in GitHub [here](https://github.com/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/blob/main/src/import/external/vpython/basic/sphere_3.ipynb) nor in nbviewer [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/blob/main/src/import/external/vpython/basic/sphere_3.ipynb).

It also does not work with [binder](https://mybinder.org/) as [here](https://hub.gke2.mybinder.org/user/dudung-py-jupyter-nb-qnn1mtpg/doc/tree/src/import/external/vpython/basic/sphere_3.ipynb).

Is there any solution to display it correctly online?

Comment: Binder should be working. For that line, the 'here' link you post was to your temporary session and so it doesn't work. Did you try launching from the 'launch binder' badge at the [VPython-Jupyter repo page here](https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter#sample-program)? Your code from [here](https://github.com/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/blob/main/src/import/external/vpython/basic/sphere_3.ipynb) makes a canvas of three colored balls. The part you didn't understand about nbviewer is that it won't run a notebook, it just renders the code and output of what it can handle of past run notebooks and ...

Comment: <continued> mostly that means the nbviewer output can show the code as text and the output as text or render images. Only certain things, such as Plotly plots, that have javascript underlying them remain in some way active in nbviewer. VPython needs an active Python kernel to render the interactive canvas and so that is why you see nothing when you view it in nbviewer. Github's rendering is even more limited, for example Plotly plots don't render like they do in nbviewer. So always consider nbviewer as the best for sharing 'static' notebooks and Github is still just a preview.

Comment: Thank you for your effort in answering my question, @Wayne. I am trying to digest the information slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your code can be seen to work in a MyBinder-served session with VPython installed

Go to [the VPython-Jupyter repo page here](https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter#sample-program) and click on the 'launch binder' badge. **A session will launch where VPython is installed and working.**

Make a new cell in the index page that comes up. Now you can copy your code out of your two cells [here](https://github.com/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/blob/main/src/import/external/vpython/basic/sphere_3.ipynb) and paste it in and run it. Here's the code to make that easy:

```py
from vpython import*
scene = canvas()
ball1 = sphere(pos=vector(-5,-3,0), radius=0.5,color=color.blue)
ball2 = sphere(pos=vector(5,-3,0), radius=0.5,color=color.red)
ball3 = sphere(pos=vector(0,5,0), radius=0.5,color=color.green)
```

It will work in that temporary session and you'll see three colored balls. You should be able to use your middle mouse button to zoom in out of the triangle of three spheres.

---

### Alternative for online VPython: Glowscript / Web VPython

If you just want to share VPython output separate from Jupyter and Python, there is a [Glowscript / Web VPython](https://www.glowscript.org/) that allows you to develop and share them.

Example, [here](https://www.glowscript.org/#/user/GlowScriptDemos/folder/Examples/program/AtomicSolid-VPython).
Based on looking at the bottom of the source HTML for that page there is a way to share links without having to sign in.
I haven't used it.

---

---

Clarifications related to your post:

##### How MyBinder knows what to provide you

The MyBinder service needs to know what to install so it uses configuration files found in the repo you point at it. You cannot just go to MyBinder.org and spin up a vanilla session and expect complex things like VPython to work. Most code uses one or a few extra packages to work and those need to be specified so they environment in the session matches your needs. Your repo at https://github.com/dudung/py-jupyter-nb has no configuration files and so it is going to be the basic, vanilla set up that binder makes. Essentially just Python connected to Jupyter notebook interface and JupyterLab. It's not going to run VPython.

**How could you make it so you can share your code and the session will have VPython installed?** I suspect if you made a file in the root of your repository named `requirements.txt` and put the contents of [the VPython repo 'requirements.txt' file](https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter/blob/master/requirements.txt) in there. (Or just copy that file to your repo.) Then launches from https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/main?filepath=src%2Fimport%2Fexternal%2Fvpython%2Fbasic%2Fsphere_3_static.ipynb might work.

Note that I say **'suspect'** and **'might'**. I haven't tried it recently myself, and so I cannot be certain. There's a lot of moving pieces involved and so sometimes one part has a minor bug that makes the whole process not work as expected.

**There's also Glowscript / Web VPython** that should allow working and sharing online, see section above.

##### How to share MyBinder launch URLs

Don't share the links to a session because they won't work later. You want to share the launch URL. It will have `https://mybinder.org/v2/` near the start of it, such as:

```bash
https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/vpython/vpython-jupyter/7.6.1?filepath=index.ipynb
```

You shared in your post:

```bash
https://hub.gke2.mybinder.org/user/dudung-py-jupyter-nb-qnn1mtpg/doc/tree/src/import/external/vpython/basic/sphere_3.ipynb
```

(Try putting that in your browser and you'll see what others trying it see.).
You may be able to note the difference at the start now that I gave you some idea about the pattern.

The other big signal that your link was to a temporary is that `qnn1mtpg` tag in there. That's part of the access code for it. You'd not want to normally share that but the session is temporary and so it is already gone like several minutes after you no longer use it anyway.
(I actually put the launch URL for your repo and notebook in the section 'How MyBinder knows what to provide you'; it's https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/main?filepath=src%2Fimport%2Fexternal%2Fvpython%2Fbasic%2Fsphere_3_static.ipynb )